# inline assembly error while compiling linux kernel 2.4.0

Tags: gcc, assembly, linux-kernel, inline-assembly

I am trying to compile linux kernel 2.4.0 on Ubuntu 15.10 32-bit. I receive this errors while building:

linux/include/asm/checksum.h:161:2: error: missing terminating " character
linux/include/asm/checksum.h:173:3: error: missing terminating " character
...

What gcc is complaining are the quotations in the inline assembly:

```
static __inline__ unsigned short int csum_ipv6_magic(struct in6_addr *saddr,
                                                     struct in6_addr *daddr,
                                                     __u32 len,
                                                     unsigned short proto,
                                                     unsigned int sum)
{
        __asm__("
                addl 0(%1), %0 //line 162
                adcl 4(%1), %0
                adcl 8(%1), %0
                adcl 12(%1), %0
                adcl 0(%2), %0
                adcl 4(%2), %0
                adcl 8(%2), %0
                adcl 12(%2), %0
                adcl %3, %0
                adcl %4, %0
                adcl $0, %0
                "                    // line 173
                : "=&r" (sum)
                : "r" (saddr), "r" (daddr),
                  "r"(htonl(len)), "r"(htonl(proto)), "0"(sum));

        return csum_fold(sum);
}
```

I am not sure why this happens. Is it because incompatible gcc version? My current gcc version is 
gcc (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 5.2.1 20151010.

Comment: Could you please indicate which are lines 161 and 173? And why do you have code implementation in a header file?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to have opening and closing quotes around each instruction? I.e. `"addl 0(%1), %0\n\t"`, etc.

Comment: @WeatherVane Just added line number comment. This is linux kernel source code 2.4.0 not what I wrote. Since it is inline function I think it is normal to be in header file.

Comment: @Michael I am also confused. So I am not sure if it is some older gcc syntax. This is production linux kernel code so I don't think it's some kind of mistakes.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Yes just trying to learn kernel code not really using the image. Since it is smaller code base.

Comment: If that's the actual kernel code, then it's broken and relying on non-standard behaviour. You can probably coax GCC into accepting it with the right options, or you can fix it like Machael suggested. Remove the double quotes on line 161 and 173 and put double quotes at the start and end of each line in between. For example, `"addl 0(%1), %0"`.

Comment: Please confirm your kernel version.  `2.4.0` seems wrong (circa 2004).  Do you mean `4.2.0` which is very current.  What version exactly?

Comment: @CraigEstey It's an ancient version 2.4.0. Just for learning purpose.

Comment: I've been writing linux kernel/device drivers for 20+.  2.4.0 is _too_ ancient.  And, IMO, hence the compile problems with a modern gcc.  If you want ancient but similar, use `2.6.x`.  At `kernel.org` you can get `2.6.32.69`.  I was being kind. `2.4` was obsolete in 2004 [was popular for conservative R/T embedded uses for a while], but now too old, particularly if you're learning.  And, if you truly want 2.4, 2.4.0 was the first issue.  I'd use 2.4.<latest>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multi-line string literals are not supported by recent gcc. Newer (2.4.0 is ancient!) versions of the kernel have:

```
    asm("addl 0(%1), %0     ;\n"
        "adcl 4(%1), %0     ;\n"
```

etc. It used to be supported, for instance in [version 3.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Multi-line-Strings.html), but the support was removed in [3.3](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-3.3/changes.html):

> The preprocessor no longer accepts multi-line string literals. They were deprecated in 3.0, 3.1, and 3.2.